# flutter-web: what's the best way to open a detail part of web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I can write the things as just pages of widgets.
But I would expect better way, since I think it's a normal case in web.

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Include a list of  content with `IconButton()` in a widget.
2. After run with `flutter run -d chrome`, it will display in chrome.
3. I try to click each button in list to open the detail.

#### Expected 2 possible result:

1. Open the detail part in the list part area.
2. Or open the detail with a new tab, but better to share the menu & top part.
    I don't think this is the same case of https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33126.

I can implement to open the detail page combine with menu & top part, but I don't like this way for web.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `ExpansionTile` widget in a `ListView` widget to get the expected *Result-1* as follows.

A live example is available in this [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/f43563168d9a67fe4faa1a796d7d605f).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyExpansionTile(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyExpansionTile extends StatelessWidget {

  // defining the title and descriptions.
  final List<String> titles = ['title-1', 'title-2', 'title-3'];
  final List<String> descriptions = [
    'Description for title-1',
    'Description for title-2',
    'Detailed Description for  title-3'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {

        // handle index out of range.
        if(index >= titles.length)
          return null;

        // build and expansion tile for each title and description.
        return ExpansionTile(

          // comment following to show an arrow in the end of each expansion tile as per material design.
          trailing: Container(width: 0, height:0),          

          leading: Icon(Icons.open_in_browser),          
          title: Text(titles[index]),
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(descriptions[index]),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

This will render the expansion tiles as show below. The expansion tile is clickable and expands and collapses on click.

[image]